# How to use the rows of a csv as keys of Node.js object?

Tags: node.js, csv, iteration

I need to create a map in Node.js that matches a list of ids from a csv to a number.

The csv file looks like this:

```
participant_membership_id
32533
4986
5494
5650
5666
5673
5674
5680
5907
6064
...
```

And I need the map to be like this:

```
{
  32533: 0
  4986: 0
  5494: 0
  ...
}
```

The default values are 0.

I got to the part where I have the map as an output of:

```
fs.createReadStream("./data/participant__memberships_ids_mysql.csv")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => {
        csv_ids.push(data)
    }) 
    .on("end",()=>{
        const cardinality_mapping = {}
        for (const row of csv_ids) {
            const keys = Object.values(row)
            cardinality_mapping[keys[0]] = 0
        }
        console.log(cardinality_mapping)
  })
```

And I have the desired outcome:

```
  '33597': 0,
  '33598': 0,
  '33599': 0,
  '33600': 0,
  '33601': 0,
  '33602': 0,
  '33603': 0,
  '33604': 0,
  '33605': 0,
  '33606': 0,
  '33607': 0,
  '33608': 0,
  '33609': 0,
  '33610': 0,
  '33611': 0,
  '33612': 0,
  '33613': 0,
  '33614': 0,
  '33615': 0,
```

The problem is that when I want to access this object later in the code, for example with

```
console.log(cardinality_mapping)
```

It tells me the object does not exists.
What am I doing wrong?

Attaching my whole code:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon")
const _ = require("lodash")
const { db } = require("./firebase")
const fs = require("fs")
const csv = require("csv-parser")
const csv_ids = []
let cardinality_mapping = {}

//const csv_rows = csv_ids.split('\n')
//console.log(csv_rows)

fs.createReadStream("./data/participant__memberships_ids_mysql.csv")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => {
        csv_ids.push(data)
    }) 
    .on("end",()=>{
        const cardinality_mapping = {}
        for (const row of csv_ids) {
            const keys = Object.values(row)
            cardinality_mapping[keys[0]] = 0
        }
        console.log(cardinality_mapping)
  }) 

console.log(cardinality_mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

So after you changed your question the answer is that you define `cardinality_mapping` inside of the callback function. Move it outside of the callback and it should work.

```
+ const cardinality_mapping = {}
  fs.createReadStream("./data/participant__memberships_ids_mysql.csv")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => {
        csv_ids.push(data)
    }) 
    .on("end",()=>{
-       const cardinality_mapping = {}
        for (const row of csv_ids) {
            const keys = Object.values(row)
            cardinality_mapping[keys[0]] = 0
        }
        console.log(cardinality_mapping)
  })
```

Comment: The problem here is that is I call for cardinality_mapping later in the code, it comes back empty.

Comment: Example, If I try to print the map after the createReadStream, It is still empyt.
```let cardinality_mapping = {}


  fs.createReadStream("./data/participant__memberships_ids_mysql.csv")
    .pipe(csv())
    .on("data", (data) => {
        csv_ids.push(data)
    }) 
    .on("end",()=>{
        for (const row of csv_ids) {
            const keys = Object.values(row)
            cardinality_mapping[keys[0]] = 0
        }
        //console.log(cardinality_mapping)
  })

  console.log(cardinality_mapping)```

Comment: then your code has a bug else where, try adding more log statements or use a debugger with breakpoints.

Comment: I added the rest of my code

Answer (score -1):

```js
/* load this from file*/
const csv =
  `participant_membership_id
32533
4986
5494
5650
5666
5673
5674
5680
5907
6064
`
const csv_rows = csv.split('\n')
// remove first entry (row with the column titles)
csv_rows.shift();

const result = {}
for (const row of csv_rows) {
  const fields = row.split(',')
  const participant_membership_id = fields[0]
  result[participant_membership_id] = 0
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
```

Comment: The problem is that the list of ids is in a csv because I have 28k recrods.